# Passing some (any) kind of context info from SSAS connection string to underlying database

Tags: sql-server, ssas, connection-string, ssas-tabular

I'd like to have an option to "kind of" impersonate user in SQL database. Is there any part of connection string to analysis server that is passed further into connection string of the underlying database ? In my scenario SSAS instance is using direct query for querying the analytical database.

There are ways how to pass some kind of context to the SSAS itself via connection string, namely:

- `CustomData`
- `Extended Properties`
- `Application Name`

However as far as I can tell nothing is being passed to the underlying SQL database.

---

**Long story**

I have a complex system with permissions "calculated" on SQL level - which is not going to change. Internally this is implemented in a way that application connecting to SQL server calls `SET CONTEXT_INFO` to setup the user context. In order for SSAS/tabular/DirectQueryMode reports to work correctly I need to set the context info on SQL level like any other client application. SSAS allows you to create your own SQL provider in which you can set this context, however (from the logs and experiments) although SSAS allows you to set some kind of optional context (like `CustomData` in connection string) there seems to be nothing that is being passed on into the SQL database.

Comment: What is the version of the sql server?

Comment: How do you use SSAS? Do you use it from .NET or Report Server...?

Answer (score 2):

Are you on SSAS 2016? If so, you can definitely do it. Refer to the [SQL BI whitepaper on DQ](http://www.sqlbi.com/articles/directquery-in-analysis-services-2016/) that came out in January. It contains explanation and instructions for how this works.

From the whitepaper,

> "When you use DirectQuery, the model has a single connection, which
>   has a particular configuration for impersonation (this is the property
>   impersonationMode in the JSON file, but it is called Impersonation
>   Info in SSMS, and just Impersonation in SSDT)."

I assume these are Windows users you are impersonating. You need Kerberos constrained delegation to make it work.

To set this in SSMS, go to your connection properties, find the Impersonation Info setting, and change it to Use The Credentials Of The Current User